# Change MM/DD/YYYY to DD/MM/YYYY in CSV

Tags: python, csv

I have this csv file, however it is formatted in MM/DD/YYYY

[Image of the Months in the CSV](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QEnzG.png)

Similar answers have not resolved it,

Solution attempted:

1. Format the cells with custom d/m/yyyy
   [Image shown here][2]

Comment: You need to close & re-open the file (for writing).

Comment: Thank you, Scott i have solved the issue of reversing the CSV

Comment: Your CSV program could easily be reformatting the appearance of dates. First thing to do is open it in a plain text editor and verify the *actual* dates you stored; if it's just how Excel (or whatever) displays them, you just change the formatting for that column in Excel.